# How do I achieve a "Water Ripple" effect on typography?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography

Trying to achieve something like this text treatment, but not sure where to start.

[image]

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/355573333059851007/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a displacement map in Photoshop.

All you need is a greyscale image to use for the displacement; which you need to save as a PSD in greyscale mode (*Image → Mode → Grayscale*). Then go to *Filter → Distort → Displace...* on the layer you want to distort, hit OK and choose your displacement image PSD.

Take this quick example:

[image]

With this as a displacement map:

[image]

Which gives us this:

[image]