# How can I replicate this distorted text effect in After Effects?

Tags: typography, text, adobe-after-effects, distort

I need to replicate the effect used on the type here using After Effects (it's for a school project where we are not allowed to use any other program.)

[image]

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a displacement map.

Similar to how I explained to do so in Photoshop [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/86189/52050) ...you need to find an appropriate image (or video clip) to use for the displacement. Then use a Displacement Map effect with that clip as the source to create the distortion.

If you want a static effect then obviously you use a static image, or if you want the effect to be dynamic and move then you need to find an appropriate video clip to use...

I'll show you an example using [this rippling water video clip](https://www.videezy.com/nature/1810-dancing-on-water-stock-video):

[image]

Create your type:

[image]

Place your displacement source clip in your composition and hide it.

Add a Displacement Map effect to your type and set the "Displacement Map Layer" to the hidden clip. Adjust the horizontal/vertical displacement amount to your liking:

[image]

You should now have something like this:

[image]

Getting the right effect really hinges on you finding (or creating) an appropriate displacement map for your needs (I used the first clip I came across and spent about 2 minutes putting it together).